# Choosing elements of the list based on vector R

Tags: r, list, vector, indexing

I have a very large list `mylidt` where each element corresponds to a sequence of years represented by `myYears` - short example below. The elements of the list were not named. I have then vectors `goodyear` `badyear` and `neutralyear` and I would like to use them to create three new lists each taking correct elements from the list. For `goodyear` it would be element `[[2]]` and `[[5]]` etc. what is an elegant way to do it?

```
A <- seq(900,1000,1)
B <- rnorm(101,10,2)
C <- rnorm(101,10,2)
D <- rnorm(101,10,2)
E <- rnorm(101,10,2)
G <- rnorm(101,10,2)
H <- rnorm(101,10,2)
I <- rnorm(101,10,2)
J <- rnorm(101,10,2)
K <- rnorm(101,10,2)

mylist <- list(A,B,C,D,E,G,H,I,J,K)

myYears <- seq(1981,1990,1)

goodyear <- c(1981,1985)
badyear <- c(1984,1986,1990)
neutralyear <- myYears[!myYears %in% c(goodyear,badyear)]]
```

Comment: `mylist[myYears %in% goodyear]` would do it

Comment: Perfect thanks so much!